# Armar una matriz aplastando botones de una interfaz en Tkinter los cuales extraen datos de columnas de un archivo excel

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Buenas noches quisiera pedir ayuda.
De la matriz en excel que se muestra a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero extraer los valores numéricos de las columnas A,C y E para formar una matriz como la que se muestra a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

valores numericos extraidos de las columnas A,C y E respectivamente

No obstante yo quiero hacerlo, mediante esta interfaz que he desarrollado en Tkinter al presionar los botones A, C y E
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente he programado de tal forma que al aplastar los botones, se extraiga las columnas del  archivo en excel, como se muestra a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo yo quiero formar una matriz solo con los valores numéricos ¿como puedo hacerlo?
nota: me gustaria diseñarlo de tal manera que armar la matriz agrupando cualquier columna del archivo excel por ejemplo A,B y C o D,F Y G

Anteriormente he logrado formar la matriz extrayendo los valores numéricos de las columnas A,C y E
empleando el siguiente codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from tkinter import*
ventana=Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x600")
ventana.title("Prueba")
def A():
    import pandas as pd
    datos= pd.read_excel('proyecto matriz.xlsx')
    print(datos.iloc[:,0:1])

def B():
    import pandas as pd
    datos= pd.read_excel('proyecto matriz.xlsx')
    print(datos.iloc[:,1:2])
def C():
    import pandas as pd
    datos= pd.read_excel('proyecto matriz.xlsx')
    print(datos.iloc[:,2:3])
def D():
    import pandas as pd
    datos= pd.read_excel('proyecto matriz.xlsx')
    print(datos.iloc[:,3:4])

def E():
    import pandas as pd
    datos= pd.read_excel('proyecto matriz.xlsx')
    print(datos.iloc[:,4:5])
def F():
    import pandas as pd
    datos= pd.read_excel('proyecto matriz.xlsx')
    print(datos.iloc[:,5:6])
def G():
    import pandas as pd
    datos= pd.read_excel('proyecto matriz.xlsx')
    print(datos.iloc[:,6:7])
    
botonA=Button(text="A",command=A).pack()
botonB=Button(text="B",command=B).pack()
botonC=Button(text="C",command=C).pack()
botonD=Button(text="D",command=D).pack()
botonE=Button(text="E",command=E).pack()
botonF=Button(text="F",command=F).pack()
botonG=Button(text="G",command=G).pack()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor agrega el código en texto, revisa [ask]. Recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: si haces `df.to_dict()` te devuelve un diccionario cuyas claves son los nombres de las columnas, es decir A,B,C,D,...